# Can I stop migration from my PC to new MacBook Pro without loosing what has already migrated?

Tags: migration-assistant

Can I stop migration from my PC to my MacBook pro without loosing what has already migrated? I did not unplug my external drive and it is now migrating the backup.

Answer (score 1):

Since Migration Assistant tool has no pause / suspend button (and in the past when it did, it deleted the files and cleaned up if my memory is correct) you might get unexpected results on one or more files if you abort things.

- [Cancelled wireless Migration Assistant... best way to start over?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30071/cancelled-wireless-migration-assistant-best-way-to-start-over)
- [iMac-to-iMac Migration was interrupted; Now, source iMac is reading as 0.0GB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/imac-to-imac-migration-was-interrupted-now-source-imac-is-reading-as-0-0gb)
- [Migration Assistant moved files to inaccesible new account, how to get to my old files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59919/migration-assistant-moved-files-to-inaccesible-new-account-how-to-get-to-my-old)

As you can see, even Mac to Mac transfers which are supposed to survive a disconnect are sometimes not resilient. I believe a PC to Mac transfer is much simpler and akin to copying files, so you might only have one file that got corrupted if you interrupt things.

If you abort the transfer, all the files will be copied, but there is no guarantee they left a workable user account. In almost all cases, you can then log in and get to the files that have transferred, but you will want to clean things up / hand move things to the correct location.

Since Migration Assistant doesn't move an entire PC user over, you might be fine with what transferred, but you have no way of knowing what has been transferred without puling the plug (so to speak).

Comment: I would say "Yes", you can stop it, and then carry on with your provisos

Comment: @stuffe I've updated this with some links. It's been a while since I did a PC to Mac transfer so I could be entirely wrong about the stop button. I suppose I'll get a comment soon enough if I did mess that item up.

Comment: Think you are right, there is no stop button, but you can kill the process with standard quit options etc.